# How i can change root to user directory?

Tags: command-line

I want to change root directory back to home directory, how can I achieve this?

What I have now:

```
root@raselkhan:~# pwd
/root
```

What I had before:

```
khan@raselkhan:~# pwd
/khan/home
```

Comment: You want to change `root`'s home directory or `cd` to your home directory?

Comment: Default i've khan/home after command sudo -i then changes /root

Comment: That's the point of `sudo -i`. If you don't want that, don't `sudo`.

Comment: I want back to before, when type pwd then showing me /home/khan

Comment: Then use `sudo -s` instead (a **shell** but not a **login shell**)

Comment: Still not showing before

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can always:

```
exit
```

And then `pwd` again.

Answer (score 1):

In your first portion `root@raselkhan:~# pwd`, the username is `root` and the directory you are currently in is `~` i.e. home directory. As the user is `root` and the home directory of `root` is `/root`, `pwd` command rightly showing the print working directory as `/root`.

Now in your second portion `khan@raselkhan:~# pwd`, the username is `khan` and the current directory is `~` which again means the home directory of the user. As the user in this case is `khan` so the `pwd` will show `/home/khan` (i think you have mistakenly typed `/khan/home`).

Comment: yes, my username khan, I want default directory /khan/home when type pwd

Comment: Then don't be `root`. The `pwd` command will show `/home/khan` when the prompt starts with `khan@raselkhan:~`.